# Spring Data Jpa Repository not saving entities to database

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Im having some difficulties using jpa. Im not getting any exceptions, but I cant save anything to the database. I went from Hibernate to Jpa and everything worked perfectly there. Below are my Files

application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.ch.generali=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:party;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class NewClientFormWrapper {
   //Entity
   NaturalPerson person;
   //Entity
   Address[] addresses;
   //Entity
   CommunicationChannel[] communicationChannels;

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface NaturalPersonRepository extends JpaRepository<NaturalPerson, Integer> {

    Optional<List<NaturalPerson>> getNaturalPersonByFirstname(String inputFirstname);

    Optional<NaturalPerson> getNaturalPersonById(int id);

    void deleteNaturalPersonById(int id);

}
```

Service:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/partner")
public class PartnerService {

@Autowired
NaturalPersonRepository naturalPersonRepository;

@PostMapping(value = "/client")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<NewClientFormWrapper> newClient(@RequestBody @Valid NewClientFormWrapper 
request) {

    request.getPerson().setAddresses(Arrays.asList(request.getAddresses()));
    request.getPerson().setCommunicationChannels(Arrays.
       asList(request.getCommunicationChannels()));
    NaturalPerson naturalPerson = naturalPersonRepository.save(request.getPerson());

    NewClientFormWrapper response = NewClientFormWrapper.builder()
            .person(naturalPerson)
            .addresses(naturalPerson.getAddresses().toArray(new Address[0]))
            .communicationChannels(naturalPerson.getCommunicationChannels().toArray(new 
             CommunicationChannel[0]))
            .build();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
  }
```

I'm getting a 200 Response when submitting the form, but can't find the data in the database

Comment: You are looking for data in where?

Comment: in the database, you see i have made a ui with a table, where all the users get displayed, after I create one I can see the user in the table, but not in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a run time database(H2) so when you are calling APi data is showing from memory. No data is persisted in actual database. To persist the data in actual database you need to set the below properties with actual database url and driver

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:party;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Comment: Worked! Since I'm using postgres I also changed the driver to postgres.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, albeit with a different cause, and didn't find my solution mentioned in any of the "Spring Data JPA not saving" questions so I wanted to share what I found here in case it might help someone else.

I had the correct `@Transactional` annotations, but I did not have a correct `PlatformTransactionManager` bean.  I copy/pasted code from another project that created a `JdbcTransactionManager`.  I changed this to a `JpaTransactionManager` and it worked.  Interestingly, having the wrong transaction manager did not cause any errors; the app would run but not even try to save the entities.  If I added a call to the repository `flush` method (or used `saveAndFlush`), it caused a 'not in a transaction' error but a call to `save()` was silently ignored.